# PCF Update Service Error

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcf

I'm using CF CLI (6.32.0) to connect with my PCF. I'm trying to update my existing service with the JSON Object. But I'm getting the below error.

> Invalid configuration provided for -c flag. Please provide a valid JSON object or path to a file containing a valid JSON object.

I tried by giving the example provided through help option. But still getting the same error.

`cf bind-service myapp mydb -c "{\"permissions\":\"read-only\"}"`

Anyone help me on resolving this issue?

Thanks
Siva

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you using?

It looks like your example should work on Windows, but for Linux or OSX you would do:

`cf bind-service myapp mydb -c '{"permissions":"read-only"}'`

Comment: You might also enable verbose output from the `cf` cli (`-v` flag).  What you'd want to look for in the output is if the error is coming from the cf cli or if it's coming as a response from an HTTP request sent by the cli.  If the error is from the cf cli, you probably won't see any HTTP requests sent, and that would probably just mean your JSON is badly formed.  If there is an error from a response, it could indicate that fields you've added in the JSON are incorrect, since the remote service broker is capable of doing more in-depth validation than the cf cli.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 Operating System.

Answer (score 0):

The json formatted delimiters required by different operation systems are also different.
The best way is enter the json content in a json file. It can solve the format problem between different systems.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work in Windows this way:

```
cf bind-service myapp mydb -c "{"""permissions""":"""read-only"""}"
```

cf version 8.4.0+b4c083e10.2022-06-02